# Using ginput in my code returns the error: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, ginput

I'm trying to figure out how ginput(3) works in this code, but when I run it, it returning a UserWarning saying: "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, "

Please help me out on this.

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *
im = array(Image.open('empire.jpg'))
imshow(im)
print ('Please click 3 points')
x = ginput(3)
print ('you clicked:',x)
show()
```

**UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, "**

Comment: This can be taken literally. Matplotlib uses a non-GUI [backend](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends). See the link on how to change the backend.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So what can be done to eliminate this warning that I'm facing ?

Comment: Follow the instructions in the link to set a different backend.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that did the work, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a quick look at what a backend in matplotlib refers to, by checking out [this](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends) link.

Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for providing me with the necessary resource.

```
import matplotlib

#Use the line below to set a backend for matplotib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('empire.jpg'))
imshow(im)

print ('Please click 3 points')
x = ginput(3)

print ('you clicked:',x)
show()
```

You could try out these other GUI backends in the given order, if "TkAgg" doesn't work out for you.

- WX
- QTAgg
- QT4Agg